# Why is my "while" condition not being met?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, stack, postfix-notation

I have been running this and typing "12+" as the expression. When it gets to the while loop it gets stuck as if the condition is never met. I dont see why this is because right before the while loop "it" is equal to 2 so the loop should not even be used.

```
//array based stack implementation
class Stack
{
private:
    int capacity;        //max size of stack
    int top;            //index for top element
    char *listArray;       //array holding stack elements

public:
    Stack (int size = 50){ //constructor
        capacity = size;
        top = 0;
        listArray = new char[size];
    }

    ~Stack() { delete [] listArray; } //destructor


    void push(char it) {    //Put "it" on stack
        listArray[top++] = it;
    }
    char pop() {   //pop top element
        return listArray [--top];
    }

    char& topValue() const { //return top element
        return listArray[top-1];
    }

    char& nextValue() const {//return second to top element
        return listArray[top-2];
    }


    int length() const { return top; } //return length



};

int main()
{
    string exp;
    char it = ' ';
    int count;
    int push_length;


    cout << "Enter an expression in postfix notation:\n";
    cin >> exp;
    cout << "The number of characters in your expression is " << exp.length() << ".\n";
    Stack STK;

    for(count= 0; count < exp.length() ;count++)
    {

        if (exp[count] == '+')
        {
            it = exp[count - 1];
            cout << it << "\n";


            while (it != 1 || it != 2 || it != 3 || it != 4 || it != 5 || it != 6 || it != 7 || it != 8 || it != 9 || it != 0)
            {
                cout << it << "\n";
                it = exp[count--];
            }

            STK.push(it);
            //cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";

            it = exp[count --];
            if (it == 1 || it == 2 || it == 3 || it == 4 || it == 5 || it == 6 || it == 7 || it == 8 || it == 9 || it == 0){
                STK.push(it);
                cout << it;
            }
            cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";
            it = STK.topValue() + STK.nextValue();
            STK.pop();
            STK.pop();
            STK.push(it);
            cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";

        }


    }
    cout << "The number of characters pushed into the stack is " << STK.length() << ".\n";
    push_length = STK.length();



    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are comparing against char value 1, which is not the same as char value '1'.

Comment: A problem with a loop either running indefinitely or not executing as anticipated is a great time to learn to use a debugger. Search for how to use a debugger with whatever compiler and ide you are using. Essentially it will allow you to run the program, then pause it right before the loop and inspect all the values of the variables. You can even watch certain variables and expressions. ie you could find out if it != 1 is true or false at any point during execution. I started using a debugger after programming for a long time, I wish I learned earlier.

Comment: I've rolled your question back. With your edit, the question doesn't make sense. If you have more questions about the fixed code, please open a new question.

Answer (score 6):

As you mention, your `while` clause is always `true`.

```
while (it != 1 || it != 2 || it != 3 || it != 4 || it != 5 || it != 6 || it != 7 || it != 8 || it != 9 || it != 0)
```

`it` will always **not** be **some of those numbers**.

You *could* change every `||` to `&&` in that statement, since that is likely what you meant.
And change `1` to `'1'`, `2` to `'2'`, and so on...

A clearer approach would be:

```
while ( !std::isdigit(it) )
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: ok so i went the easier route and used the while (!isdigit(it)). Thanks for that tip!

Comment: Now i'm down to trying to add the top value and next value and it keeps giving me the result 'c'. Im looking for 3 so its not far off and I know its because it a char value but is there any way to get that 'c' and convert it to 3?

Comment: @RichardRyan Post that as a new question and you'll get a lot more eyes on it.  And if you think this answered your posted question, mark it as *accepted* and you'll get a nice bump to your reputation.  :)  Good luck!